# Bracket's Support of Groovy

Tags: groovy, code-formatting, adobe-brackets

I try to use Brackets to edit Groovy and GSP files, which were detected and had the right syntax highlights. But when I tried to beautify the file, I always get the alert of "Could not determine the file type".

Is there any fix to this?

Comment: do you have an example of the before and after?

Comment: Beautify the file does not do anything, except raising the alert. It seems that Beautify does not recognize Groovy file type.

Comment: I end up with a brutal workaround, directly editing the brackets-beautify extension file `~/Library/Application Support/Brackets/extensions/user/brackets-beautify/main.js` on Mac, making groovy use the beautifier of js, gsp the one of html